# What's wrong with this php pdo code?

Tags: php, pdo

The foreach won't echo anything out, anybody knows what's wrong with it?

Note: $checks is the value of checkboxes.

```
<?php
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'foo';

    try{

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);

        $checks = $_POST['checks'];

        $post = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title= ' ". $checks ." '";

        foreach($db->query($post) as $row){
            echo $row['title'] . '' . $row['body'];
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'CONNECTION UNSUCCESFUL!';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your code is prone to sql injections, see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra spacing around the title? So the title with the extra spaces around it never gets a match from the your database.

```
WHERE title= ' ". $checks ." '";
```

Change to

```
WHERE title= '". $checks ."'";
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks, man. You know just what the mistake is even though I don't show any database things to you, ingenious!

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title IN (' ". implode("','", $checks) ." ') ";
```

if $checks is array then you should use like this

Comment: I can echo out $checks just fine

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. I'm sure your answer will be useful for me in the future, I'll keep implode() in mind when dealing with array next time, thanks! XD